# fastest way to subsitute on 10GB file for multiple expressions

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, perl

I have a file of 10GB data, I want to execute 2048 substitution expressions of `sed -i 's/pattern/replace_pattern/g'` on that file.

Is there a way to do it faster and effectively.

Currently, I am launching `sed` or `perl`  in sequential order.

```
sed -i  "s/VSS:F31128015/VSS_F31128015/g" file.data
sed -i  "s/VSS:F31127969/VSS_F31127969/g" file.data
 OR
perl -pi -e  's/VSS\:F31128015/VSS_F31128015/g' file.data
perl -pi -e  's/VSS\:F31127969/VSS_F31127969/g' file.data
```

I did notice very less difference in speed of execution by `perl` or `sed`
Is there a better way to do this? I have almost 2048 expressions of replacement.

will opening 10GB file via `Tcl/tk` and using `regexp` be a better idea?

Should I use [lex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_(software))?

Comment: Maybe you can *compact* these patterns somehow. `s/VSS:/VSS_/g` is the extreme example, it may match too many fragments though. Something with `[:digit:]`? It strongly depends on your data and the patterns.

Comment: I have a list of the expressions on which I need to perform substitution, giving `s/VSS:/VSS_/g` will result in the greedy fashion.

Comment: Build a file so you can `sed -f`. In what format are these "2048 substitution expressions". Are they in a file. How does the file look like? Maybe all you need is `sed -f subst data`.

Comment: I have a file with the list of all 2048 `sed` or `perl` expressions.

Comment: Are you wanting to hack an RC extracted netlist?

Comment: yeah, It is my prime goal @RakeshSharma

Answer (score 3):

Some things that should work (untested)

## Use a more general regex

```
sed -i -e 's/(VSS):(F[0-9]+)/\1_\2/g' file.data
```

## Use more than one expression, but one `sed` invocation.

```
sed -i -e "s/VSS:F31128015/VSS_F31128015/g" -e "s/VSS:F31127969/VSS_F31127969/g" file.data
```

Comment: I cannot use the first suggestion as I want to avoid the greedy expression.
I will use the second expression, Is using `perl` instead of `sed` advisable in this context?

Comment: I have no idea perl vs sed.

Answer (score 0):

perl is good for simple text replacements like this. Following up on your comment thread on ctrl-alt-delor's answer, there are ways to avoid greediness. In this case, are you wanting to match exactly 8 digits? If yes,

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/(?<=VSS):(?=F\d{8})/_/' bigfile
```

This uses lookarounds to find the colon you want to change to underscore.

People often add the `g` flag even when there's only 1 match per line. Add it if necessary.